# Why Can I Not Get Same Locality as Apple Weather App?

Tags: cllocationmanager, cllocation

I want to display the user's city & state in my application. However, I can't seem to get the desired city to populate.

I am currently in New Albany, OH. Apple's Weather app displays that correctly:

[image: Screenshot of Apple's Weather app for iOS]

However, when utilizing `CoreLocation`, I am getting Columbus, OH.

Here is a map of my current location (New Albany), displaying the proximity to Columbus, OH:

[image: Screenshot of Apple's Maps app for macOS]

When I `print` the received `CLPlacemark`, I get the following:

```swift
7070 Bayton Pl, 
7070 Bayton Pl, New Albany, OH  43054, United States 
@ <+40.10695990,-82.82727340> +/- 100.00m, 
region CLCircularRegion (identifier:'<+40.10795920,-82.82855810> radius 296.54', center:<+40.10795920,-82.82855810>, radius:296.54m)
```

**Note** - The above `CLPlacemark` is a little inaccurate, as the address is not my address.

However, when I `print` my `CLPlacemark`'s `locality`, I get the following:

```
Columbus
```

I have my `CLLocationManager` configured as follows:

```swift
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers
locationManager.distanceFilter = 3000
```

When I have determined that the user has authorized location services, I call:

```swift
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

No matter how I configure my `CLLocationManager`, I *never* get returned New Albany as the `locality`. I have even tried setting the `CLLocationManager`'s `desiredAccuracy` to `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation` to see if that would help, but it did not.

What am I doing incorrectly that is causing me to receive Columbus rather than New Albany?

---

**Update 1**

I tried the solution below, however it was unreliable because the `String` that contains the city, state, and zip code is sometimes at the first, second, or third index, depending on the address.

*Do I need to get the `addressDictionary`, get the array of values using `FormattedAddressLines`, and then parse the city manually?*

---

**Update 2**

I printed the `CLPlacemark` that was returned, and this is what I received:

```swift
Optional([AnyHashable("Street"): 7070 Bayton Pl, AnyHashable("ZIP"): 43054, AnyHashable("Country"): United States, AnyHashable("SubThoroughfare"): 7070, AnyHashable("State"): OH, AnyHashable("Name"): 7070 Bayton Pl, AnyHashable("SubAdministrativeArea"): Franklin, AnyHashable("Thoroughfare"): Bayton Pl, AnyHashable("FormattedAddressLines"): <__NSArrayM 0x618000053fe0>(
7070 Bayton Pl,
New Albany, OH  43054,
United States
)
, AnyHashable("City"): Columbus, AnyHashable("CountryCode"): US, AnyHashable("PostCodeExtension"): 8120])
```

It's obvious that the city value, New Albany, in the `FormattedAddressLines` dictionary does not match the `CLPlacemark`'s `locality` value, `Columbus`.

---

**Update 3**

Following is the entirety of the object that retrieves the current location:

```swift
/// Retrieves the device's location.
public final class DeviceLocation: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    // MARK: - Properties

    /// Handles the delivery of the device's current location.
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    /// The object responsible for handling the device's location-based updates.
    public weak var deviceLocationDelegate: DeviceLocationDelegate?

    // MARK: - Initialization

    /// Returns an initialized `DeviceLocation` object.
    public override init() {
        super.init()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
    }

    // MARK: - CLLocationManagerDelegate

    public func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        switch status {
        case .authorizedAlways,
             .authorizedWhenInUse:
            startMonitoringLocationChanges()
        default:
            return
        }
    }

    public func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.last else {
            return
        }
        print(location)
        reverseGeocode(location)
        deviceLocationDelegate?.deviceLocation(self, didReceiveCoordinate: location.coordinate)
    }

    public func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(error)
        deviceLocationDelegate?.deviceLocation(self, didFailToReceiveCoordinate: error)
    }

    // MARK: - Helpers

    /// Requests access to the user's location while in use.
    public func requestLocationAccess() {
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        }
    }

    /// Starts tasks associated with monitoring the device's location.
    public func startMonitoringLocationChanges() {
        locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
    }

    /// Retrieves information for a location from a reverse-geocode query.
    /// - parameter location: The `CLLocation` instance.
    private func reverseGeocode(_ location: CLLocation) {
        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemarks, error) in
            if let geocodeError = error {
                print(geocodeError)
                self.deviceLocationDelegate?.deviceLocation(self, didFailToReverseGeocode: geocodeError)
                return
            }
            guard let placemark = placemarks?.last else {
                return
            }
            self.deviceLocationDelegate?.deviceLocation(self, didFinishReverseGeocodeWithLocation: (city: placemark.locality, state: placemark.administrativeArea))
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I would recommend increasing the accuracy of the locationManager and reduce the distance filter.  Also, can you show how you are checking the accuracy of the location you are using to get the place marker?

Comment: @rmp I updated the accuracy of `locationManager`, but I get the same results. I updated that in the code. I also tried reducing the distance filter, but I still got the same results. I added a third update to provide the code for the object that retrieves the current location. I monitor for significant location changes because I don't want to be constantly fetching the location by using `startUpdatingLocation`. Significant changes are preferred for my needs, but when I do change locations, I would like the location to be more accurate.

Comment: In your `didUpdateLocations` you need to check the accuracy of the location before using it. If the accuracy isn't within the tolerance you need, disregard it and wait for the next update.